# jquery blink a few

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, blink

i want to give blink effect to an element by using addClass and removeClass 3 times each
i tried this

```
$("#div").addClass("orange").delay(300).queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass("orange");
    next();
});
```

this is works just 1 time

how can i make this happened 3 times with 300 ms delay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just count to three:

```
(function() {
  var count = 0, $div = $('#div'), interval = setInterval(function() {
    if ($div.hasClass('orange')) {
      $div.removeClass('orange'); ++count;
    }
    else
      $div.addClass('orange');

    if (count === 3) clearInterval(interval);
  }, 300);
})();
```

You could get fancy and write your own animation plugin for it, I guess.